# Refresh position left element when browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JavaScript code.

```
var x   = $('.sidebar').offset().top,
offsetY = $('.left-columns').offset().left + $('.left-columns').width();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scroll >= x){
        $('.sidebar').addClass('active1');
        $('.active1').css({left:offsetY});
    }else{
        $('.sidebar').removeClass('active1');
        $('.active1').css({left:0});
    }
});
$(window).resize(function(){
         x = $('.sidebar').offset().top,
   offsetY = $('.left-columns').offset().left + $('.left-columns').width();
});
```

It works fine, but when I resize the browser window, then the problems begin with the positioning element

Comment: You need to add the pertinent css styles and html code if you want accurate answers (or any answer at all)

Comment: when you resize it will give you new `X` and `Y` but it won't change it's css, because you have it in `window.scroll`,

Comment: This question should be considered for closing due to the lack of information provided despite several attempts to persuade the OP to provide more details

Comment: Here's the problem
class at active1 scrolls and Resize it appears on disappears
http://wsc-studio.ru/problem/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you are trying to achieve but I'm guessing that you need to reposition the `.sidebar1` and `.active1` elements when the window resizes. By that I mean, on the resize handler, do exactly the same you are doing on the scroll handler...

```
$(window).scroll(updatePosition);
$(window).resize(updatePosition);

function updatePosition(){    

    x = $('.sidebar').offset().top,
    offsetY = $('.left-columns').offset().left + $('.left-columns').width(),
    scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(scroll >= x){
      $('.sidebar').addClass('active1');
      $('.active1').css({left:offsetY});
    }else{
      $('.sidebar').removeClass('active1');
      $('.active1').css({left:0});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes it works, but after another problem arises when you resize it appears disappears class active1 resulting in lost scrollable element

Comment: Well, that's a completely different problem which I can't troubleshoot due to the lack of details in your question...I don't know what exactly is `.sidebar` and `.active1`. So, please add more details to your question

Comment: We have two blocks Left (left-column) and Right (sidebar). Sidebar with scrolling window gets active1 class, which has an about style fixed up the screen and Right Block
Now resize the leaves, What class active1 to have to Out

Comment: That doesn't say much mate...you really need to post the pertinent code

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your conditions in both events, it has problems if you just put in `.scroll` event only because it doesn't respond in `.resize()` event, also if you make a separate function that will be reusable:

```
function scrlResize(){
          x = $('.sidebar').offset().top,
    offsetY = $('.left-columns').offset().left + $('.left-columns').width(),
     scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scroll >= x){
      $('.sidebar').addClass('active1');
      $('.active1').css({left:offsetY});
    }else{
      $('.sidebar').removeClass('active1');
      $('.active1').css({left:0});
    }
}

$(window).scroll(scrlResize);
$(window).resize(scrlResize);
```

Comment: Exact same problem here is that there is a class disappears when scroll active1